# Python: Group by characters before second dash

Tags: python, string, find

I have a string such as 'GH-TV-G090013'. Basically, I want to group a data frame by the region, which is the second pair of letters ('TV'). Right now, I have the code below. But the problem with this is that some regions are three letters and others are two (and some even are one). So it would be nice to group by the letters before the second dash (i.e. 'GH-TV'). Is there a way to do this?

Examples right now:
'GH-TV-G090013' becomes 'GH-TV-'
'GH-ABC-G090011' becomes 'GH-ABC' 
'GH-V-G090000' becomes 'GH-V-G'

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[:6], axis = 1).sum()
```

Comment: The string examples you gave are located in which column of your dataframe ?

Comment: Or are those the names of the columns? Could you post a little example of the dataframe you're working with?

Comment: Those are the names of the columns. The names are different codes like that. The rows are dates and the cells are just numbers.

Comment: So, the thing is your 3 examples are kinda different. In the first one you keep until the second dash. In the second one you keep just before the second dash and in the third one you keep just after the second dash. Is there any error there?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Those are just different examples of the column names. Ultimately I wan't to group everything by what is just before the second dash. But right now, I am grouping by the first six characters, which yields the examples.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Give me a moment and I can give you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are the way to go. If there's only between 1 and 3 characters before and after the first dash, this should always work:

```
import re
col_list=['GH-TV-G090013',  'GH-ABC-G090011' ,'GH-V-G090000'] 
groups=[re.search('(\w{1,3}-\w{1,3})', i).group(0) for i in lista]
df.groupby(groups, axis = 1).sum()
```

You should use `df.columns` instead of the list I used, of course. If you're not familiar with regular expressions, please tell me and I can help you

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later today.